# this.form.get is not a function in angular 13

Tags: angular, forms, web, frontend, components

I'am working on angular project and this what is appearing to me :this.form.get is not a function
I'll show you  my component :`export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit {
checkoutFormGroup:FormGroup;

totalPrice:number=0;

totalQuantity:number=0;`

//
}

now my html component:`<div class="form-area"> <h3> Review your order</h3> <p> total quantity:{{totalQuantity}}</p> <p>shipping free</p> <p>total Price: {{totalPrice}}</p> </div>`

and this is the result in the navigator :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OszI9.png)
and when I open console :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blm4H.png)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11171#issuecomment-243583467

> You don't need to add REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES or FormProviders to your module >definition. These are included when you import the ReactiveFormsModule.

> You are importing a few symbols from @angular/common. That's where the old API >lives, and it's not compatible with the new API. If you change the FormBuilder >import in your form component file to point to the new API in @angular/forms, the >form loads as expected.

Answer (score 0):

A problem could be that `this.form` is not defined. Since you're declaring it as `FormGroup` the function `get` is known by the inheritance of `FormGroup` but that's it. You need to have an instance of `FormGroup` accessible at your class.

How do you introduce the `form` your working with to the class?

As far as I can see you're only declaring it via: `checkoutFormGroup:FormGroup;`.
But you're not defining it by creating it via 'new' or injecting it to your class `CheckoutComponent`.